# What is the equivalent of .= in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

What is the equivalent of the ".=" operator in Excel VBA?

I'm wanting to add strings to a variable. Below throws an error due to the `.=`

```
query .= """Job"".""Estimate Number#1"" = '" & est & "' OR "
```

Comment: `query = query & "some string"`

Comment: @emodendroket Thanks, that is too obvious for me to have seen. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: OK, you got it.  Unfortunately VBA can get quite wordy with these sorts of problems.

Comment: @vba4all Not everyone here is an experienced programmer.  Kind of hard to Google if you don't know what terms/thing you're looking for.  There is at least some effort in this question as far as concisely describing the result desired, the error encountered, and a minimum sample of the code required to reproduce it.

Comment: @emodendroket Thank you for the help, people like you is what keeps this site alive and helpful. Thanks for the support with my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such operator; you have to use the combination of the regular concatenation and assignment operators instead, like so:

```
query = query & "some string"
```